# VB.NET Windows 7 64bit Write File in C:\Windows\System32

Tags: vb.net, windows-7-x64

I'm having a massive problem trying to write a file into the c:\windows\system32 directory. The code works fine on 32 bit machines, however does not work on 64 bit machines.

My user account is an administrator on the machine, and even right clicking and choosing to run the app as administrator does not solve the issue.

When writing the file, no exception is thrown, but the file is not written.

I have read various posts regarding adding an app.manifest file containing the requestedExecutionLevel node to my solution, but as yet am unable to get this to work. I have a feeling this may be because I'm using vb.net rather than c#.net

Has anybody encountered this issue before? I'd be delighted if somebody could provide an example VS2010 VB.Net project with a correctly configured app.manifest file as I'm a little unsure whether my attempts at setting this up are correct.

(also, this is not a malicious app I am writing, I'm working on a version control app for our team and need to be able to interface with IIS files held in c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config).

Thanks
David

Comment: I'm wondering it's some anti-virus software deleted it after you wrote it

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention UAC is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the file is written under UAC Virtualization and located under `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Windows\System32`

[Windows Blog](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows/b/developers/archive/2009/08/04/user-account-control-data-redirection.aspx) - Tips on what is going on behind the scenes.

[TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2006.05.firstlook.aspx) - Look under Data Redirection

Under Local Sercurity Policies there is the following option which controls UAC Virtualization.

[image: UAC Virtualization Option]

Comment: Thanks for the information, I've just ran process monitor and found that although I'm hard codeing to write to c:\windows\system32. The file is actually being written to c:\windows\SYSWOW64!

Comment: Hmm, any ideas how to stop this happening?